# OpenCV: For displaying a video, why does the while loop has 2 variables set to myVideo.read()

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

## Here is the code

```
# import libraries of python OpenCV    
import cv2  
   
# import Numpy by alias name np  
import numpy as np  
   
# capture frames from a camera   
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
   
# loop runs if capturing has been initialized   
while (1):  
   
    # reads frames from a camera   
    ret, frame = cap.read()  
   
    # Display an original image   
    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
```

## why the "ret"?

## it is never used and without it the video does not even play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cap.read()` returns a tuple consisting of a boolean and an array (frame)

```
(True,array_here)
```

```
# reads frames from a camera   
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

`ret` can either be false or true depeding on whether a frame has been grabbed or not.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1)

Comment: Thank you for the short and lucid answer, now that I know what .read() returns, that makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67734448/7456923).

It is a pretty standard practice, in particular in C++, that functions only return a boolean indicating the success of the function, while the "real output" (here, the frame that you want) is given by changing the content of a pointer given as argument to the function. It is the case for the C++ version of [`VideoCapture.read()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1).

Now you a re using the Python interface for the same function. Since pointers are not really used in Python, the outputs (here, the video frame) are also returned by the function, as an addition to the "normal output" (i.e. the boolean indicating success of the reading).

This is why the function returns two elements, one boolean for success, one array for the frame.